# Can I Cancel a Mobile SDK Login?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am working on mobile iOS and Android apps for our Community, and am using the Salesforce Mobile SDK to handle OAuth. We are using [deferred login](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2015/03/deferred-login-mobile-sdk-for-android-native-apps.html) so that we can provide limited guest access to the site. The issue we're seeing is that the SDK screen does not provide a Cancel or Back button, which would be useful in case a user accidentally triggers the login flow.

Is there a way to cancel or back out of SDK's OAuth flow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on iOS you can call SFLoginViewController's shouldShowBackButton method. 
On Android the device's back button should work.  I would advise you extend the login view on each platform to further customize the back behavior.